# Combining a List of Pandas Data Frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, concatenation

I am trying to union a list of pandas data frames in jupyter notebook. When I use pd.concat([i]), wrapped in a for-loop, I only get the first dataframe. When i check the length of the list prior to the concat, I have 189 data frames in the list.

I do some data cleaning techniques prior to appending each DF to the list. My goal is to have one dataframe where I can correctly order the DF by the "Date" column and run subsequent analysis. How can I combine the 189 dataframes. All the DF have the same column names.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    csv_files = glob.glob('*csv*')

    Sept = []
    allDF = []
    for i in csv_files:
        Sept.append(pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(i)))
    for i in Sept:
        col = i.columns[1].split(" ")[0]
        i.insert(0, "Date", col)
        newHead = i.iloc[0]
        i = i[1:]
        i.columns = newHead
        i = i.rename(columns = {i.columns[0]: 'Date'})
        i = i.fillna(method = 'ffill')
        grouped = i.groupby('Product Name')
        i = i[grouped.cumcount(ascending=False) > 0]
        i = i.drop(0, axis = 1)
        allDF.append(i)
    for i in allDF:
        unionDF = pd.concat([i], ignore_index=True)
    unionDF
```

Comment: You don't need the final for loop just do `unionDF = pd.concat(allDF)`

Comment: In the final loop you're creating a new dataframe each time by concatenating a list of one dataframe `i`

Comment: That worked! *facepalm* ... Thank you

Comment: `df=pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_files])` will load and concatenate all CSVs. If all files have the same schema you only need to make modifications once, after loading all of them as a single dataframe. If not, a good idea would be to extract the transformation code into a separate function so you can use `df=pd.concat([transform(f) for f in csv_files])`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Very wise to put them in a DF first. Thanks for the optimization tip.